# NoReverseMatch error when running tests in Django

Tags: python, django

i'm using python django 
i had error while running the tests.py 
what does that mean :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hala/Desktop/lasting/sharesoft-13/project/tager/tager_www/tests.py", line 82, in test_saving_comments
    response=c.get(reverse('adingcomment', kwargs={'post_id' : 1, 'content':'hjhgh'}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 496, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 416, in _reverse_with_prefix
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'adingcomment' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'content': 'hjhgh', 'post_id': 1}' not found.
```

Comment: Two things: 1. Post the code that raises the error (at least the relevant piece) and a brief description of what you are doing. 2. I suggest you to change the title of your question to something more descriptive about your problem. As it stands right now, I think there's no way anyone can help you

Comment: I am having same issue. I am trying to reverse() on a named URL. The built in tests are failing.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Django was unable to find a route which would match that particular path name and arguments, and thus was unable to generate a URL by reversing the route.

Perhaps `adingcomment` was a typo, and should have been `addingcomment` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The `reverse('adingcomment', kwargs={'post_id' : 1, 'content':'hjhgh'})` failed to find a URL route.

Perhaps you registered a `addingcomment` route instead? You need to check the name of the route and the provided arguments to match an existing route you registered. For more details see the [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) documentation.