# reverse() call in middleware fails in test

Tags: python, django

Whenever I try to use reverse() inside middleware it fails when running tests `manage.py test` with error like this

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 416, in _reverse_with_prefix
"arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

middleware.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class TestMid (object):
def process_request(self, request):
    target = reverse('home_custom')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'test_django.views.home', name='home_custom'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('path to page %s' % reverse('home_custom'))
```

I don't have any test written. I am simply running tests that came with Django.

This looks like a question similar to [NoReverseMatch error when running tests in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953287/noreversematch-error-when-running-tests-in-django) but that question was left unanswered.

Django 1.5.1 and 1.5.2

Comment: Can you show your root urls.py ?

Comment: Its posted. There are no apps. Just new plain Django project with a middleware

Comment: This is failing because a default Django project comes with no URLs called 'home', but on every request made (via tests, or whatever) you're attempting to reverse that URL.

Comment: I don't think thats true about the default 'home' URL. I never read about it, but I changed it to home_custom and it still fails

Comment: Just tried Django 1.6. The issue is gone but mostly because `manage.py test` does not run built in tests now.